# Help with proof (by induction) for unbiasedness of an estimator

Tags: statistics, solution-verification, induction, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am reading a paper where the following estimator is used for estimating the sample mean from a series of observations/data-points $\{r_1, r_2,....,r_n\}$:

$$ r_n = \lambda_n p + (1-\lambda_n) \hat{p_{n-1}} $$, where $\hat{p_{n-1}}$ is defined as:

$$ \hat{p_{n-1}} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} r_i}{n-1}$$.

For more context, it is assumed that the observations $\{r_1, r_2,....,r_n\}$ are collected sequentially, i.e., first $r_1$ is observed, followed by $r_2$ and so on. Also the subsequent $r$ values depend on the previous values.

It is given that $$\mathbb{E}[r_1] = \mathbb{E}[\hat{p_{1}}] = p  $$, where $p$ is the $\textbf{true}$ estimate of the sample mean.

It is claimed in the paper that the estimator $r_n$ is an unbiased estimator of the true mean $p$. The proof in the paper works as follows by induction:

Base case $$\mathbb{E}[r_1] = \mathbb{E}[\hat{p_{1}}] = p  $$. Then by induction:

$$\mathbb{E}[\hat{p_{n}}] = \frac{(n-1) \mathbb{E}[\hat{p_{n-1}}] + \mathbb{E}[r_n] }{n} \\ 
= \frac{ \lambda_n p + (n-\lambda_n) \mathbb{E}[\hat{p_{n-1}}]   }{n} \\
= p $$

I don't understand how 3rd step is derived from the second step.

$$\mathbb{E}[r_n] = \mathbb{E}[\lambda_n p + (1-\lambda_n) \hat{p_{n-1}}] \\ 
= \lambda_n p + (1-\lambda_n) \mathbb{E}[\hat{p_{n-1}}] \\
= p $$

Is this correct? From my understanding, for proof by induction, first base case should be correct, followed by assuming the statement for some value $k$, followed by extending it for case $k+1$. In this proof, I couldn't generalize from $r_k$ to $r_{k+1}$ (or from $\hat{p_{n}}$ to $\hat{p_{n-1}}$).
They use these equations for the final proof of unbiasedness as follows:

Comment: Ir $r_n$ supposed to be an observation or an estimator?  In either case why is its calculation based on $p$?  What does a "true estimate" mean?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I should have added some context. This model is for user ratings, and r_n is the nth observed user rating for an item in the paper. 'True estimate' here means the 'true preference' of the item, i.e. proportion of users who actually like the item. The weighted sum indicates that the observed rating is biased by the true preference and the observed preference. The paper then claims it's an unbiased estimate.